# How can I create a bundled package with dependencies bundled individually

Tags: javascript, webpack, bundling-and-minification, webpack-4, code-splitting

I have a requirement to create a JavaScript framework for a third party plugin where the plugin can use any dependencies and any versions of those dependencies that it wants to without conflicting with other third party plugins that are used on the same page.

I've also got to think about sharing the dependencies between plugins so that we don't end up with x number of plugins all using the same dependency and version and bloating the page with x number of the same dependency.

My initial idea was to use Webpack to bundle the third party plugins, but I'd need to have separate bundles for each individual dependency to reduce page bloat.  So I added this config to the config for webpack:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        pluginX: './src/index.js',
    },
    devtool: 'source-map',
    target: 'web',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
        library: 'pluginX',
    },
    optimization: {
        moduleIds: 'named',
        chunkIds: 'named',        
        splitChunks: {
            chunks: 'all',
            name(module, chunk, cacheGroupKey) {
                const context = module.context;
                const splitContext = context.match(/[\\/]node_modules[\\/](.*?)([\\/]|$)/);

                const packageJson = getPackageJson(context);
                const version = packageJson ? packageJson.version : '0.0.0';
                const name = splitContext[1].replace('@', '');
                return `${cacheGroupKey}-${name}-${version}`;
            },
        }
    },
    plugins: [
        new CleanPlugin('./dist', {
            verbose: false,
        }),
    ]
}
```

For reference the `getPackageJson` function looks like this:

```
function getPackageJson(context) {
    do {
        const packageJson = `${context}\\package.json`;
        if (fs.existsSync(packageJson)) { return require(packageJson); }
        const splits = context.split(/\\/);
        splits.pop();
        context = splits.length > 0 ? splits.join('\\') : undefined;
    } while (context);
    return undefined;
}
```

I've set up three test plugins, 1 using d3 v5.9.1, and the other 2 both using d3 v3.5.17.  Using this configuration, I can correctly bundle up the plugins and their dependencies separately, I've created a test server to serve the bundled entry bundles and the dependency bundles.  Plugin 1 using d3 v5.9.1 seems to work fine consistently, but plugin 2 and plugin 3 never work together; one of them will always be undefined when I try to access the plugin name (specified in the `output.library` property).

For reference, here is the index.html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="./vendors-d3-3.5.17.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="./vendors-d3-5.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="./plugin1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="./plugin2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="./plugin3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body></body>

</html>
```

The index.js gets added automatically by the HtmlWebpackPlugin I'm using (I'm using webpack-dev-server to test this).

The index.js page that is the test page for this is this:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    plugin1.run();
    plugin2.run();
    plugin3.run();
}, 1000);
```

plugin 1 index.js file looks like this:

```
import * as d3 from 'd3';

export function run() {
    console.log('plugin1', !!d3.scaleLinear, !!(d3.scale || {}).linear);
}
```

plugin 2 and 3 has this as their index.js file:

```
import * as d3 from 'd3';

export function run() {
    console.log('pluginX', !!d3.scale.linear, !!d3.scaleLinear);
}
```

The console output should read:

```
plugin1 true false
plugin2 true false
plugin3 true false
```

But I actually get either this:

```
plugin1 true false
plugin2 true false
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'run' of undefined
```

or this:

```
plugin1 true false
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'run' of undefined
```

Because either plugin2 or plugin3 (always only one of them) is always undefined.

I suspect it has something to do with the bootstrapping code that webpack inserts, but I can't be 100% sure about that.

Comment: For clarity, in your example code where you have pluginX you have in your actual code plugin2 or plugin3?

Comment: @TedFitzpatrick Yes, that's correct.